# "confound" has two meanings and I'm confused which definition was used in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> As candidates **confound** worries about immigration, Islam and terrorism, the campaign will turn toxic.

I looked up the dictionary and I found two possible definitions

1. to cause a surprise or confusion.
2. to prove something wrong.

My guess is number 2.

source: http://www.theworldin.com/edition/2017/article/12593/fight-france

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/confound), there is a third definition of **confound**, which is to mix up (something) with something else.

In many countries in Europe, people are worried about terrorism. Right-wing politicians try to influence voters by mixing up two ideas: 1) immigrants are muslims. 2) terrorists are muslims. People will then worry that immigrants are terrorists, and vote for parties that oppose immigration (the right-wing parties).